# Oferecer recompensa para uma boa pergunta. Por que não?

Tags: novo-recurso

Isso passou agora pela cabeça depois de ver [esta boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111689/%C3%89-correto-nomear-atributos-de-tags-html-de-maneira-arbitr%C3%A1ria). De repente seria até uma forma de incentivar as pessoas a fazerem perguntas melhores... mas tá, ok, sei que não faz muito sentido... Mas então, porquê mesmo? :)

Comment: Como funcionaria?

Comment: Parece ser algo interessante. A SE daria a recompensa? Como seria acionado/escolhido o que recompensar? Certamente manual, né? Não precisa fazer uma proposta completa, acho que depois pode ser refinado, mas desenvolva a ideia.

Comment: Poderia haver uma fila de recompensa para uma boa pergunta. Nesta fila, apenas pessoas com mais de 10k poderiam avaliar. Se houver + de 5 avaliacoes a favor da recompensa, o AP ganharia 5 votos positivos na pergunta, pelas 5 pessoas que avaliaram. Se eu não me engano, isso soma 10 pontos, ou seja, é como se os 5 avaliadores tivessem votado positivo na pergunta. A questão é decidir como a pergunta apareceria na fila. Nesse caso, uma pessoa com mais de 10k poderia sinalizar a pergunta para que a mesma caia na fila de recompensa.

Comment: Enfim, as recompensas são os próprios votos de pessoas com > 10k. A diferença é que a file de recompensa vai direcionar as coisas. É muito mais fácil aparecer numa fila, do que sair procurando perguntas boas pra votar.

Comment: Então Gabe, à princípio pensei no funcionamento normal: se achei a pergunta boa, ofereço uma recompensa de X pontos meus ao autor da pergunta. Não teria destaque por isso, apenas uma recompensa pela pergunta excepcional.... Mas gostei da ideia do cantoni combinada com a do @bigwon... a SE daria a recompensa quando tivesse mais votos de usuários com alta reputação, ou mesmo com uma quantidade X de pontos... se bem que já tem medalha pra isso né...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha proposta: **Uma Fila de Análise pra Perguntas Boas**.

Como funcionaria:

A Fila de Análise para Perguntas Boas seria um lugar onde pessoas com reputação alta poderiam decidir se a pergunta que está sendo analisada merece uma recompensa ou não. A princípio pensei que somente pessoas com mais de 10k de reputação poderiam fazer análise nessa fila.

Para que uma pergunta caia nessa fila, uma pessoa também com mais de 10k de reputação deveria fazer uma sinalização. Portanto, no quadro de opções de sinalização deveria aparecer mais um item.

Como a pessoa que sinalizou concorda que a pergunta é boa (já que ela está sinalizando), então seriam necessários 4 análises positivas para que a recompensa seja dada.

Caso 4 pessoas (com mais de 10k), analisem positivamente, então a pergunta ganha 5 votos (sendo que o primeiro já foi dado pela pessoa que sinalizou).

A recompensa são os 5 votos mais uma medalha de Boa Pergunta. Essa medalha seria concedida sempre que uma pergunta do mesmo usuário fosse bem avaliada.

Existe um fator psicológico também, que é saber que sua pergunta foi bem avaliada por pessoas que tem boa reputação. É sem dúvida outro fato motivador.

Creio que esse mecanismo não é de difícil implementação por parte da SE e não precisa ficar pensando em outros tipos de recompensa.

Comment: +1 Boa ideia, ;)

Comment: Tbm achei interessante... +1

Comment: Acho a intenção bem válida, mas da maneira que está sugerida não consigo ver o que essa fila faria que não poderia ser igualmente feita com pequenos ajustes no algorítmo da página inicial. Também não tenho certeza sobre a equivalência de que algo que foi votado por alguém com mais de 10k seja automaticamente digno de mais atenção.

Comment: Eu gosto da ideia de ter uma fila – não sei se concordo com os detalhes de implementação, mas isso importa menos. @Gabe Uma fila sempre será mais focada que a home, aí que está a vantagem. As perguntas vão sendo apresentadas uma a uma e você vai avaliando. Em termos de navegação, é bem mais prático que a home.

Comment: Pensei na fila, pois como o @bfavaretto disse, já é um mecanismo familiar para avaliar perguntas e respostas. Sobre os 10k, foi um número arbitrário, pode ser menos, entretanto, creio que a pessoa que avalia já deve ser bem acostumada com a cultura do SOpt. Perguntas que são boas aqui, podem não ser consideradas em outro SO ou outro lugar e vice-versa.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo com você em relação à atenção da fila. É a parte da ideia que mais me atrai também. Mas também me preocupo com a percepção de uma "fila das coisas boas", e o potencial de abuso disso.... Foi o que eu disse, eu apoio a intenção - só não acho que encontramos uma implementação ideal ainda